# Finding $\int_0^{\pi/8} x\sin 2x\,dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

I have a trigonometric equation, when integrated and evaluated should be a specific value. I cannot get that value.

The question: $$\int_0^{\pi/8} x\sin 2x\,dx$$

The answer should be 
$$\frac{4-\pi}{16\cdot 2^{1/2}}$$

--this is written in the book.

Comment: Did you try integration by parts ?

Comment: Do you know integration by parts?

Comment: @Peter Sadly I do not, is that what it involves, as I could try to learn it?

Comment: @molarmass Sadly I do not, is that what it involves, as I could try to learn it?

Comment: Without integration by parts, I cannot see how the integral can be calculated.

Comment: @ Peter, okay, in the section of the book where the question was, there was not explation of integration by parts, but I will try to look into it. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The rule works as follows : $\int u'(x)v(x)dx=u(x)v(x)-\int v'(x)u(x)dx$

Comment: If you use $u'(x)=sin(2x)$ and $v(x)=x$, you will suceed. The other way $u'(x)=x,v(x)=sin(2x)$ will fail. Try it.

Comment: @Peter, why do you need to use integration by parts?

Comment: @Gurjinder You don't  *need* integration by parts, but it's a popular (and quite elementary) method for this sort of problem. For another method, please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: rewriting as $$\frac{1}{2}\int 2x\sin(2x)dx$$ we set $$2x=t$$ we obtain $$\frac{1}{4}\int t\sin(t)dt$$ and now integrate this by parts

Comment: you are welcome, the result should be $$\frac{1}{4} \left(\frac{1}{4} \sin (2 t)-\frac{1}{2} t \cos (2 t)\right)$$

Comment: Cheers, why do you need to use integration by parts on this problem?

Comment: since an $t$ stands befor the sinus-function

Comment: Would you use integration by parts for this problem, as I know how to integrate this: ∫ x^3 sin(3- x^3) dx

Comment: a better example will be $\int x^3\sin(x^3)dx$

Comment: yes and integrated would be: -x/3cos(x^3) =

Comment: and the constant of integration, right?

Comment: no, sorry your solution is not correct, since $\int\sin(x^3)dx$ has no solution in the known elementary functions a better example will be $$\int x^3\sin(x)dx$$

Comment: oh okay, would the second integral, evaluated be: -x^3cos(x) +c?

Comment: no, the solution is given by $$3 \left(x^2-2\right) \sin (x)-x \left(x^2-6\right) \cos (x)+C$$ hint: read an article about partial integrating

Comment: okay, thanks for the help

Comment: As a rough guide, if the integrand is the product of two functions (as you have here) then you should be thinking integration by parts. 

I think of integration by parts as the "inverse-product rule" --- Indeed, that is how you can prove the formula --- So if I see a product in an integral, then I think integration by parts

Answer (score 2):

Integration by parts is the "obvious" choice here, but I wanted to post an alternative method which I think is pretty darn cool. That's the Feynman-popularised (and later "The Big Bang Theory-popularised") trick of introducing a parameter and differentiating under the integral sign.

Let $\displaystyle f(x,k) = \int(-\cos kx)dx$

Note that $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial k} = \int x\sin kx dx$

Now $\displaystyle f(x,k) = -\frac{1}{k}\sin kx$

So $\displaystyle \frac{\partial f}{\partial k} = \frac{1}{k^2}\sin kx - \frac{x}{k}\cos kx$

Hence $\displaystyle \int x\sin kx dx = \frac{1}{k^2}\sin kx - \frac{x}{k}\cos kx + C$

Note that we've solved a whole "class" of problems of the form $\displaystyle \int x\sin kx dx$. All that remains is to substitute $k=2$ to get the appropriate indefinite integral:

$\displaystyle \int x\sin 2x dx = \frac{1}{4}\sin 2x - \frac{x}{2}\cos 2x + C$

And finally work out the definite integral for the required bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Notice, using product rule as follows  $$\int_{0}^{\pi/8}x\sin (2x) dx$$

$$=\left[x\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cos (2x)\right]_{0}^{\pi/8}-\int_{0}^{\pi/8}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cos (2x)dx$$

$$=\left[\frac{\pi}{8}\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)\cos\frac{\pi}{4}-0\right]+\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{2}\sin (2x)\right]_{0}^{\pi/8}$$
$$=-\frac{\pi}{16}\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}+\frac{1}{2}\left[\frac{1}{2}\sin \frac{\pi}{4}-0\right]$$
$$=-\frac{\pi}{16\sqrt 2}+\frac{1}{4\sqrt 2}$$ $$=\frac{4-\pi}{16\sqrt 2}$$